# post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required in an api with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

```
// Creating one
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    category: req.body.category,
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.body.author,
    postDate: req.body.postdate,
    postTags: req.body.posttags
  })
  try {
    const newPost = await post.save()
    res.status(201).json(newPost)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

I am working with API server in node but after asking for the POS call from client end the response is

post validation failed: title: Path `title` is required.

the model for mondoDB is

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  category:{
    type: String,
    required : true
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  author :{
    type : String,
    required : true
  },
  postDate: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
  },
  postTags : {
    type : Array,
    default : ["Coding"]
  }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('post', postSchema)
```

Answer (score 3):

Given you are using express. This goes in the main file after app initialization. So that your application is able to parse data from the json it is receiving from front end.

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't use body parser you won't be able to access those data. So please check that out.

For those who not installed body parser follow this steps.

Run this common on terminal/cmd on project root path (installing body parser)

```
npm i body-parser
```

Import bodyParser on main file

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
```

Use middle wire ( Choose only one that's correct for you based on the type of data you pass to POST request)

```
a. router.use(bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/*+json' })); // parse various different custom JSON types as JSON
b. router.use(bodyParser.raw({ type: 'application/vnd.custom-type' })); // parse some custom thing into a Buffer
c. router.use(bodyParser.text({ type: 'text/html' })); // parse an HTML body into a string
```

Also do your imports above

```
// Creating one
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const post = new Post({
    title: req.body.title,
    category: req.body.category,
    content: req.body.content,
    author: req.body.author,
    postDate: req.body.postdate,
    postTags: req.body.posttags
  })
  try {
    const newPost = await post.save()
    res.status(201).json(newPost)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: err.message })
  }
})
```

More on body parser : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

Comment: where where I have to  import them

Comment: Make all imports on top of file... Make sure you are using body parser properly.